# Can't convert string to number javascript what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

var d_long;
var d_lat;

```
a = "37.333941,-121.879065";
var comma = a.search(",");

d_lat = a.slice(0,comma); 
d_long = a.slice(comma+1,-1); 

Math.floor(d_lat);
Math.floor(d_long);

alert(d_lat + " " + d_long);

var x = d_lat+d_long;

alert(x);
```

Thanks guys I understand what I was doing wrong. I will try split instead of my weird splice. I think I will use d_lat = Number(d_lat);

Comment: im curious as to what are you using the added lat+long value for

Comment: Another question, do you really want the floor of your lat and long values?  This will lose a lot of important information about the locations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
...
var x = Number(d_lat)+Number(d_long);
...
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `parseFloat` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 2):

`Math.floor` does not transform the input, it returns the number.

```
d_lat = Math.floor(d_lat);
```

Should do it.

Comment: Please note that `Math.floor()` rounds the number down, making it an integer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: Also it all comes down to pointers, pointed datatypes and non-pointed ones, I would also mention this if I wanted a 10/10 answer

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat` you need to use. Also you can on string use `split(','`), rather this weird slicing